# How to change header iframe height to increased value?

Tags: html, css, iframe, header, height

I'm trying to increase the height of this iframe for the header so that the scrollbar doesn't show up. What am I missing here?

[The header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQsTI.png)

From the index.html:

```
<header>
        <iframe src="header.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="270"></iframe>
    </header>
```

From header.html:

```
<header>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <a href="index.html" target="_parent"><img src="images/$RK6ZV6D.JPG" alt="logo" width="60%"></a></div>
```

From main.css:

```
iframe {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
}
header {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I was trying to increase the iframe height so that the bottom parts of the image would display.

Comment: ok. you are going to want to remove the `height: auto` from your iframe css since you already have `height="270"` defined on the iframe attributes

Comment: Yup! I got that and removed `iframe {}` from main.css and used `<header>
            <iframe src="header.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="240"></iframe>
        </header>` in index.html and that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use margin on your header. It helps with getting other objects close to or away from other objects:

```
p {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

For more information see [margins](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)
and [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: Gah! Nevermind! Turns out, my issue was that for some reason, the HTML wasn't recognizing the iframe height, but somehow just got it to work properly ... and then set the margin below the header to just below 0% to cover up the white space a bit. Thanks anyways!